# CATextLayer ignores NSShadow?

Tags: ios, objective-c, catextlayer, nsshadow

I have a custom `UIView` that I've created that has several custom `UIControl` instances which are non-rectangular buttons (instead of using `UIButton` instances). I am doing this because I need to be able to draw non-rectangular buttons and have them respond to taps only in their non-rectangular regions.

Because `UIControl` doesn't come with a `UILabel`, I am using a `CATextLayer` to add in this functionality. I'd like the text I am drawing (by setting `layer.string` equal to an `NSAttributedString`) to have a shadow applied to it, but it appears that `CATextLayer` ignores any `NSShadow` attributes.

I can't find any documentation to tell me either way, but in practice, the following does not work:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *s  = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
s.lineSpacing               = 0.9f;
NSShadow *shadow            = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
shadow.shadowColor          = [UIColor orangeColor];
shadow.shadowOffset         = CGSizeMake(10,10);    
NSDictionary *textAttrs     = @{NSFontAttributeName           : [UIFont someFont],
                                NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : [s copy],
                                NSShadowAttributeName         : shadow};
```

That is, the `CATextLayer` is displayed as you would expect, except for the `NSShadow`. So, the above code works exactly the same (from what I can tell) as this code:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *s  = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
s.lineSpacing               = 0.9f;
NSDictionary *textAttrs     = @{NSFontAttributeName           : [UIFont someFont],
                                NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : [s copy]};
```

Does anybody know for sure whether what I am doing is supposed to work? I am testing using the iOS 9.3 simulator, so I don't think it's an iOS 10 beta issue.

If it doesn't work that way, does anybody know of a better solution for non-rectangular `UIButton` replacements?

Comment: thanks, this helped. old question but CATextLayer of recent iOS (>10.0) still ignores NSShadow.

Comment: Still ignoring NSShadow in iOS (>12.0)